# Java SQLite Foreign Keys with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite

I am using Hibernate with SQLite. The challenge I am facing is enabling foreign keys.
I have tried passing the PRAGMA command in the connection url with no luck.

Looking in the SQLite driver I can see that there is a constructor which takes a Properties object which sets any provided PRAGMA's. How would I be able to pass this parameter with Hibernate?

**Dependencies**

- Xerial - sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar
- Hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
- Hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.2.Final.jar
- Hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work by modifying the persistence.properties file. 
I added the following property to the persistence.properties file:

```
hibernate.connection.foreign_keys=true
```

I can see the property is being passed to the connection in the console.

```
HH000046: Connection properties: {user=, password=****, autocommit=true, foreign_keys=true, release_mode=auto}
org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
```